# Why is drupal not changing the value when renderd after value change in preprocessor?

Tags: views

I wrote a preprocessor for one of my views but when i change the title value the value in my view keeps the same! But dpm show the right modified title. Why is that...do i have to save something somewhere?

```
function mytheme_preprocess_views_view(&$vars) {
    if (isset($vars['view']->name)) {
        $function = 'mytheme_preprocess_views_view__'.$vars['view']->name;
        if (function_exists($function)) {
            $function($vars);
        }
    }


function mytheme_preprocess_views_view__myviewname($vars) {
    //alter here that specific view
    $vars['view']->result[0]->field_field_title[0]['raw']['value']="Newtitle" ;
    dpm( $vars['view']->result[0]->field_field_title[0]['raw']['value']);

}
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to pass `$vars` in by reference:

```
function mytheme_preprocess_views_view__myviewname(&$vars) {
```

Comment: i tried it this way but nothing changed... also the other way @Rufein

Comment: what i was thinking: i call it from template.php...is that right?

Answer (score 2):

or return `$vars` in mytheme_preprocess_views_view__myviewname()

```
function mytheme_preprocess_views_view(&$vars) {
if (isset($vars['view']->name)) {
    $function = 'mytheme_preprocess_views_view__'.$vars['view']->name;
    if (function_exists($function)) {
        $vars = $function($vars);
    }
}


function mytheme_preprocess_views_view__myviewname($vars) {
    //alter here that specific view
    $vars['view']->result[0]->field_field_title[0]['raw']['value']="Newtitle" ;
    dpm( $vars['view']->result[0]->field_field_title[0]['raw']['value']);
    return $vars;
```

}